# How to implement fault tolerance onAzure DevOps On-premises?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am looking to build a fault-tolerant on-premise Azure DevOps server and wanted to know if this could be supported?  Does the web front end for the site support load balancing?  From what I understanding is that the SQL port of this is done using a local SQL Server—not a standalone.  Does it support external SQL? How would you implement fault tolerance in a DevOps implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to configure Azure DevOps Server in a complex topology configuration. You may refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/architecture/examples-complex-topo?view=azure-devops-2020

[image]
[image]

As in the above example, this topology is configured for fault tolerance and high performance. In addition, this topology is distributed across multiple domains, some of which are fully trusted child domains of the parent domains.

Generally speaking, the simpler the topology, the more easily you can maintain an Azure DevOps Server deployment. It's suggested to deploy the simplest topology that meets your business needs.